# Add GET parameter in htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am looking for a way to add a rule to the htaccess that will automatically add a GET parameter to a request coming in on a subdomain (the reason why is a long story and seems irrelevant).

So sub.example.com should redirect to sub.example.com?parameter=test

The problem I'm having is the circular reference. There must be a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)parameter=test(&|$) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?parameter=test [L,R=301,QSA]
```