# Undefined index error in php using model view controller

Tags: php

I'm trying to use PHP with Model View Controller Architecture. Right now I'm trying to set up my `Bootstrap.php` class so that it can recognize controller and action from the URL. I have set up the constructor to echo the controller and action in `Bootstrap.php` class. This URL:

`*/index.php/controllername/actionname`

should give the output

```
Controller: controllername
Action: actionname
```

Here's my Bootstrap.php class:

```
private $controller;
private $action;
private $request;

public function __construct($request){
    $this->request = $request;
    if($this->request['controller'] == ""){
        $this->controller = 'home';
    } else {
        $this->controller = $this->request['controller'];
    }
    if($this->request['action'] == ""){
        $this->action = 'index';
    } else {
        $this->action = $this->request['action'];
    }
    echo 'Controller: ' . $this->controller;
    echo 'Action: ' . $this->action;
}
```

Here's the index.php class:

```
require('config.php');

require('classes/Bootstrap.php');

$bootstrap = new Bootstrap($_GET);
```

Finally, here's the .htaccess code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]*)/?([a-zA-Z]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9]*)?/?$ index.php?controller=$1&action=$2&id=$3 [NC,L]
```

The problem is that it doesn't recognize the controller or the action and it gives me this error:

```
PHP Notice: Undefined index: controller in /var/www/html/testapp/classes/Bootstrap.php on line 9
PHP Stack trace:
PHP 1. {main}() /var/www/html/testapp/index.php:0
PHP 2. Bootstrap->__construct() /var/www/html/testapp/index.php:7
PHP Notice: Undefined index: action in /var/www/html/testapp/classes/Bootstrap.php on line 14
PHP Stack trace:
PHP 1. {main}() /var/www/html/testapp/index.php:0
PHP 2. Bootstrap->__construct() /var/www/html/testapp/index.php:7
Controller: home
Action: index
```

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT:

`var_dump($request)` & `var_dump($_GET)` outputs an empty array:

```
array(0) {
}
```

Comment: Is this your own framework? This is just a guess, but I bet that rewrite hoses up your $_GET.

Comment: no I'm just trying to follow a tutorial. which rewrite are you talking about?

Comment: The mod_rewrite stuff in .htaccess.

Comment: How is the `$request` variable being populated? You may want to try to `var_dump()` that to see what it contains. Sounds like it is coming through empty.

Comment: @JeremyHarris request is poulated through the url. I'm assuming when I specify /controller/action in the url it picks that up

Comment: It can't magically "pick it up". Your `index.php` file should be bootstrapping the application and, from what I can tell, putting your request parameters in an array to pass into the Bootstrap class. Check there.

Comment: @JeremyHarris shouldn't this line `$bootstrap = new Bootstrap($_GET);` do that? I'm not sure what you mean by 'bootstrap the application'

Comment: Just `var_dump($request);` and `die;` to see what you get. If you share it here, we can try to understand what is going on.

Comment: @Rüzgar I did and it gave me an empty array. Edited the question to include that

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem, but it is working for me actually, if i manually type url. So there may be a problem with htaccess file. The URL's are correct i assume.

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19666357/add-get-parameter-in-htaccess)

Comment: @Rüzgar turns out I had to  set `allowOverride` to `all` else the .htaccess file wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, setting `AllowOverride` to `All` worked. In Ubuntu 16.04, edit the /etc/apache2/apache2.conf file and change

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

to:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

and then restart the server. You might need to do `sudo a2enmod rewrite` to enable module rewrite.